# Error in Using Make Install on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, installation

i'm trying to install graphviz,
so i downloaded the source code packages from this link [Source Code Packages](https://graphviz.gitlab.io/_pages/Download/Download_source.html)

but when i'm trying to install the webdot by using make install, this is the output:

```
sudo make install
mkdir -p /var/www/cgi-bin /var/www/html
echo "#!/usr/bin/tclsh8.3" > /var/www/cgi-bin/webdot
echo "set LIBTCLDOT /usr/lib/graphviz/libtcldot.so.0.0.0" >> /var/www/cgi-bin/webdot
echo "set CACHE_ROOT /var/cache/webdot" >> /var/www/cgi-bin/webdot
echo "set GS /usr/bin/gs" >> /var/www/cgi-bin/webdot
echo "set PS2EPSI /usr/bin/ps2epsi" >> /var/www/cgi-bin/webdot
echo "set LOCALHOSTONLY  1" >> /var/www/cgi-bin/webdot
cat /home/sadeamooz/Downloads/webdot-2.30/cgi-bin/webdot >> /var/www/cgi-bin/webdot
cp /home/sadeamooz/Downloads/webdot-2.30/cgi-bin/webdot.tclet /var/www/cgi-bin/webdot.tcl
chmod +x /var/www/cgi-bin/webdot
cp -r /home/sadeamooz/Downloads/webdot-2.30/html/webdot /var/www/html/
rm -rf /var/cache/webdot
mkdir -p /var/cache/webdot
chmod 700 /var/cache/webdot
chown apache:apache /var/cache/webdot
chown: invalid user: ‘apache:apache’
Makefile:51: recipe for target 'install' failed
make: *** [install] Error 1
```

what is the problem?

Comment: the message is very clear: `chown: invalid user: ‘apache:apache’` you have to create a user Apache and assign him to the Group Apache (which may also created)

Comment: can you instruct me more?
sorry, i'm not so professional with Linux.